# Is it possible to run KVM from a virtual installation of RHEL 6?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kvm

I am currently studying for the RHCSA exam that requires me to practice with KVM.

Is it possible to run for me to run KVM on an RHEL 6 virtual machine before I go to the trouble of partitioning my hard disk for a dual boot configuration.

If it is useful information, I am running W7 as the host machine, using VirtualBox as my virtualization software and my processor has Intel vt-x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVM needs VT-X, because you are in a virtual machine this is not possible to get to. Hence it is not possible to run KVM in Virtualbox.

VT-X doesn't get passed through to your other virtual machines, so virtual machine-ception doesn't work.